# Trying to make item's availability to NO and not available(cant issue) if the stocks are 0 but it seems the item still getting issued

Tags: java, mysql, availability

I'm trying to make item's availability to NO and not available(cant issue) if the stocks are 0 but it seems the item still getting issued.

Here's the code for the issuance of the item:

```
String sql = "insert into issueditem(Item_No,Item ID, Item Name, Issued Date, "
           + "Due Date,  Item Number, Stock) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

try {      
    connect()
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, txtitemno.getText());
    pst.setString(2, itemid.getText());
    pst.setString(3, itemname.getText());
    pst.setString(4, txtidate.getText());
    pst.setString(5, txtredate.getText());
    pst.setString(6, itemnum.getText());
    pst.setString(7, stock.getText());

    pst.execute();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item issued");
    update();

} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
} finally {
    try {
        rs.close();
        pst.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Here's my method of updating the stocks  and the availability of the item if the stocks are 0 to NO

```
public void update(){ 
    int st = Integer.parseInt(stock.getText()); 
    int q = 1;
    int sup = st - q;
    String s = String.valueOf(sup);
    stock.setText(s);
    try {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(s);
        if (n>=0){
            String val1= itemid.getText();
            String val2 = stock.getText();
            String val3=jt14.getText();
            String sql = "update storageitem set ItemID='"+val1+"', "
                    + "Stock='"+val2+"' where ItemID='"+val1+"'"
                    + "Available= 'NO' where Stock='"+val2+"'";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Updated");
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item is not issued");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }finally{
        try {
            rs.close();
            pst.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209483/discussion-on-question-by-jay-trying-to-make-items-availability-to-no-and-not-a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query is wrong, so if I understood well, you want to change the availability to 'no' if the `ItemId` = `val1` and if  `val2` = 0

```
public void update(){ 
    int st = Integer.parseInt(stock.getText()); 
    int q = 1;
    int sup = st - q;
    stock.setText(sup+"");
    try {
        String val1= itemid.getText();
        String val2 = stock.getText();
        String val3=jt14.getText();
        if (sup>=0 && val2.equals("0")){
            String sql =  "update storageitem set Available = 'NO',  Stock= '"+val2+"'"
            + " where ItemID='"+val1+"' ";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Updated");
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item is not issued");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }finally{
        try {
            rs.close();
            pst.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
}
```

you don't need to convert `sup` to a String value. and in `stock.setText()` you can put an int value of `sup` concatenating with an empty String `sup+""` 
`sup` = `st-q` which is the same value of `n` , so no need to convert it to String then reconvert it to int, use directly `sup` (just for better performance)

Comment: i tried doing that but it seems like i can still issue an item and the availability is not changing to "NO" also the stocks are still 1( currently i changed the stocks to 1 to see if the availability changes to NO and the stocks to 0)

Comment: did you tried my query after editing it? because at first I didn't understand well, try to copy it it again

Comment: We did that query inside the "Record Updated", should we do another if statement for the "Record not Issued because you have 0 stocks left and the availability is NO"

Comment: I tried doing that query but it seems like the stocks are not going down to 0 and the availability is still YES but the item got issued.

Comment: After I issued an item the message dialog "Book Issued" pop up then the message dialog inside the update() method "Book is not Issued" pop up too




            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Book issued");
            update();
            clearField();

Comment: The 1 stock item got issued but it didnt change to 0 stock left and the availability is still YES.